# Почему происходит ошибка при добавлении триггера?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, innodb, триггер

1 триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_visits` AFTER INSERT ON `visits`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `statistics` (`a_id`, `date` ,`visits`, `created`) VALUES (`NEW`.`a_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `visits`=`visits` + 1, `updated` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

2 триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_operations` BEFORE INSERT ON `operations`
 FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE _typeName VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE _subTypeName VARCHAR(32);
```

При вставке второго происходит ошибка:

```
Данный запрос не был выполнен: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `before_insert_operations` BEFORE INSERT ON `operations` FOR EACH ROW DECLARE _typeName VARCHAR(32); DECLARE _subTypeName VARCHAR(32); "
Ответ MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE _typeName VARCHAR(32); DECLARE _subTypeName VARCHAR(32)' at line 3
```

Если сделать так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_operations` BEFORE INSERT ON `operations`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE _typeName VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE _subTypeName VARCHAR(32);

END
```

То есть добавить `BEGIN END`, все работает, но почему так, ведь первый прекрасно срабатывает без `BEGIN END`? триггеры добавляю с phpmyadmin 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в первом триггере вся логика убралась в одно выражение. Во втором триггере у вас два выражения и их уже нужно оборачивать в ключевые слова `BEGIN` и `END`, чтобы анализатор понимал, что они относятся к триггеру, а не к новому SQL-запросу.